# Expectation of a function of a random variable from CDF

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

Is it possible to calculate the expectation of a function of a random variable with only the the r.v.'s CDF? Say I have a function $g(x)$ that has the property $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)dx \leq \infty $ and the only information I have about the random variable is the CDF.

For example, I have a scenario where there are three timers that can be modeled as exponential random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ with rate parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ respectively. For each moment in time I earn a reward according to some reward function $g(x)$. That is, my reward for waiting until time $t$ can be written as $\int_0^tg(x)dx$. However, $g(x)$ experiences diminishing returns so the the marginal reward received from waiting one second at $t=0$ is greater than one second at say $t=27$. This 'game' ends when one of two things happens. Either both timers $X_1$ or $X_2$ must ring or timers $X_1$ or $X_3$ must ring. I'm trying to find the expected reward of playing this game.

Currently I can calculate the the CDF of the random variable modeling the time until the game ends, but I dont know how to use this information to when what I really need is reward associated with this time.

So far I have the additional random variables:
$$ W_{12}=\max(X_1,X_2) \quad W_{13}=\max(X_1,X_3) \quad Z=\min(W_{12},W_{13})$$
Also let $F_i(x), i\in \{1,2,3\}$ denote the CDF of $X_i$
The CDF of $Z$, can be written as:
$$F_Z(t) = F_1(t)F_2(t) + F_1(t)F_3(t) - F_1(t)F_2(t)F_3(t)$$

I know when a random variable takes on non-negative values, you can use a shortcut to calculate the expectation using the CDF. That is, $E[X] = \int_0^\infty F(X\geq x)dx$. Is there something similar I could use for a function of a random variable, or is it necessary to compute the pdf of $Z$ first to compute $\int_0^\infty g(t)f_z(t)dx$

Comment: What do you mean by "only" information?  The CDF tells you *everything* about the RV that might be related to expectations!  It seems like your underlying issue might have to do with the *computational form* in which the CDF is given to you.  Please explain your circumstances.  BTW, $E[g(X)]$ can be undefined or infinite even when the integral of $|g|$ is finite.

Comment: I think you are looking for integration by parts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When $F$ is the CDF of a random variable $X$ and $g$ is a (measurable) function, the expectation of $g(X)$ can be found as a [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)

$$\mathbb{E}(g(X)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) dF(x).$$

This expresses the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

If $g$ is also differentiable, write $dF = -d(1-F)$ and [integrate by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration#Integration_by_parts) to give

$$\mathbb{E}(g(X)) = -g(x)(1-F(x)){\big|}_{-\infty}^\infty + \int_{-\infty}^\infty (1-F(x)) g^\prime(x)\, \text{d}x$$

*provided* both addends converge.  This means several things, which may be simply expressed by breaking the integral at some definite finite value such as $0$:

1. ${\lim}_{x\to -\infty} g(x)(1-F(x))$ and ${\lim}_{x\to \infty} g(x)(1-F(x))$ exist and are finite.  If so, the first addend is the difference of these two.
2. $\lim_{t\to -\infty} \int_t^0 (1-F(x))g^\prime(x)\,\text{d}x$ and $\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_0^t (1-F(x))g^\prime(x)\,\text{d}x$ exist and are finite.  If so, the second addend is the sum of these two.

A good place to break the integral is at any zero of $g$, because--provided $g$ eventually decreases fast enough for large $|x|$--that causes the first addend to vanish, leaving only the integral of $g^\prime$ against the survival function $1-F$.

#### Example

The expectation of a non-negative variable $X$ is obtained by applying the formula to the identity function $g(x)=x$ for which $g^\prime(x)=1$ and utilizing the fact that the integration may begin at zero:

$$\mathbb{E}(X)  = -x(1-F(x))\big|_{0}^\infty + \int_{0}^\infty (1-F(x))\,\text{d}x.$$

Provided $\lim_{x\to\infty} x (1-F(x)) = 0$ (that is, the survival function does not have an overly heavy tail), the upper limit of the first term vanishes.  Its lower limit obviously vanishes.  We are left only with the integral, giving the expression in the question.

Comment: Thanks, this looks exactly like I wanted. I just need to read up on my Riemann-Stieltjes integration now.

Comment: In your application, because $F$ is continuously differentiable everywhere except at $0$, you can break the integral at $0$ into two Riemann integrals and ignore the complications altogether.

Comment: What do you mean by 'complications'? Also, in your second point, should $\int_t^0(1-F(x))g(x)dx$ be $\int_t^0(1-F(x))g'(x)dx$? If not, why did the $g'(x)$ change to $g(x)$?

Comment: (1) Thank you, those primes needed to be there.  (2) "Complications" refers to needing the Riemann-Stieltjes integral instead of the Riemann integral.

Comment: Is this a bit of a circular argument? Isn't the _proof_ of the Law of the Unconscious Statistician based on the result that for a nonnegative random variable $X$, $$E[X] = \int_0^\infty [1-F_X(x)]\,\mathrm dx \quad ??$$ (e.g. the Wikipedia link that you cite for LOTUS refers to a page on math.uah,edu for the proof of LOTUS that begins with the displayed result above.

Comment: @Dilip Not at all.  LOTUS asserts that the Lebesgue integral of $x \text{d}F_X(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is the same as the Lebesgue integral of $X$ over some (original, implicit) probability space $(\Omega, \mathfrak{S}, \mathbb{P})$.

Comment: Im still having trouble with the step: $dF = -d(1-F)$. Why is this true? Is this a property of RS-integrals that I'm unfamiliar with?

Comment: This uses three basic rules of differentiation: the sum rule, the product rule, and the fact that constants have zero derivatives.

Comment: Why/how does the lower limit obviously vanish once $x \le 0$?  To me the natural extension of $F(x)$ below the  the lower bound of the domain of $x$  is that $F(x)=0$, thus $(1-F)=1$ in that region of the real line, and  as $x \rightarrow -\infty$ the lower-limit part of the boundary term diverges.

Comment: Previous comment is about the example calculation of $E[x]$ btw.

Comment: @Dave Because the calculation is for a non-negative variable.  However, my exposition of that is not as clear as it could be, so let's see whether I can make it better.

Comment: Your fix brings up the point that I made on another question: you can only get the boundary term to drop out if the lower bound of the domain of integration is 0.  Note that for a distribution  such that  $dF(x)>0$ only for $0<a<x<b$ (i.e. the domain is positive, but does not extend all the way to zero)  you need to integrate the survival function using $0$ as the lower limit of the integral (and defining $F(x)=0$ for $x<a$) in order to calculate $E(x)$.

Comment: @Dave Why does that matter? For a variable with a lower bound, you get a boundary term, so include it.  For a variable with no lower bound, sum the contributions from its positive part and negative part separately.  Indeed, the same method works for any variable. Thus, $E[X]=\int_0^\infty (1-F(x))dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(x) dx$ whenever the expectation exists. This seems not even worth discussing, because all we're debating is how one goes about evaluating an integral *via* integration by parts.  That's scarcely controversial.

Comment: This is nice. But you can give a reference for it?

Comment: @ablmf Consult any account of integration by parts.

Comment: @whuber why is this necessary $dF=−d(1−F)$ ? would you get the same result in terms of $F$ as opposed to $1-F$ if you don'y carry out that substitution?

Comment: @dleal  You can, but the point made at the end of this post is that many applications (including the one in the question) focus on positive values.  There, the integral of $1-F$ converges (provided $X$ has an expectation) but the integral of $F$ diverges for all $X.$

Comment: @whuber thank you, that clears it up

Comment: Dang, this almost solved a problem for me save that in my case $g$ is non-smooth and has an image which is just the finite set $\{ -1, 0, 1 \}$. But +1 anyway cause this is a great answer.

Comment: @galen When $g$ is not smooth at discrete points, you can break up the integral at those points and proceed in exactly the same way.  Integration by parts will potentially introduce some additive terms related to values of $g$ at those points.