# What is the Mean of a Cumulative Beta Distribution Function?

Tags: distributions

What I mean is that if we normalize the beta cdf to unity and treat it as a pdf, could we have an analytical expression for the mean of this distribution in terms of alpha and beta parameters of the Beta distribution function?

Comment: There is a *Beta distribution* and it has a *cumulative distribution function* (CDF).  The sense of *mean of the distribution* is clear, but what in what sense do you refer to "mean of the CDF"?

Comment: What I mean is that if we normalize the beta cdf to unity and treat it as a pdf could we have an analytical expression for the mean of this distributionin terms of alpha and beta parameters of beta distribution function. Let me know if this expression is meaningful then I can edit again

Comment: Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution, the mean of a Beta random variable $= \alpha/(\alpha + \beta)$. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: It sounds like you want to calculate the median, not the mean, of a beta distributed random variable.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757878/working-out-the-median-of-a-beta-function .

Comment: @Mert are you sure you want to integrate the *cdf*? What would that mean?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone My second comment was mistaken, so I deleted it. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an unusual question (with no evident applications), but it has been clearly stated, so I will answer it as written.

The mean is the expectation.  **Expectations for a distribution $F$ can be found by [integrating against the survival function $1-F$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222497/919).**

Consider any random variable $X$ whose distribution is supported on the interval $[0,1]$ with no jumps at the endpoints (like all Beta distributions).  Then according to the foregoing result,

$$\mu_{k+1}=\mathbb{E}(X^{k+1}) = \int_0^1 (1-F(x))\left((k+1) x^{k}\right)dx = 1 - (k+1)\int_0^1 x^kF(x)dx.$$

**Easy algebra gives raw moments of the unnormalized CDF in terms of moments of $X$:**

$$\int_0^1 x^k F(x)dx = \frac{1}{k+1}\left(1 - \mu_{k+1})\right).\tag{1}$$

The question asks to find the first normalized moment $m$, which is found by plugging $k=0$ and $k=1$ into $(1)$:

$$m = \frac{\int_0^1 xF(x)dx}{\int_0^1 F(x)dx} = \frac{(1-\mu_2)/2}{1-\mu_1}.\tag{2}$$

Usually we can look up the *central moments*.  In terms of them, $\mu_2$ is the variance plus the square of the mean $\mu_1$.  For the [Beta Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution),

$$\mu_1 = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$$

and

$$\mu_2 = \frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)} + \mu_1^2 = \frac{\alpha(1+\alpha)}{(\alpha+\beta)(1+\alpha+\beta)}.$$

Plug those expressions into $(2)$ (and simplify if you wish):

$$m = \frac{1 + 2\alpha+\beta}{2(1+\alpha+\beta)}= 1 - \frac{1+\beta}{2(1+\alpha+\beta)} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\alpha}{2(1+\alpha+\beta)}.$$

Comment: Apparently you didn't see the latest comment by the OP while you were composing this answer to the question which was asked (mean), not the question which the OP apparently really meant to ask (median).

Comment: @Mark I interpret that comment differently: it reads like a physical description of the center of mass of the region bounded above by the CDF.  The phrase "definite integrals of Beta CDFs" is unambiguous (although it's possible it's not what was intended!).

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the answer.

I assumed that the probability distribution of whether randomly generated numbers between 0 and 1 with uniform distribution passes a threshold or not, when the threshold takes values following the beta distribution is the normalized form of  cumulative beta distribution of the threshold values. If my assumption is correct, then I am interested in the mean of the normalized cumulative beta distribution function for my application. Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to describe.  One interpretation supposes $U$ is a uniform variable ("randomly generated numbers between 0 and 1"), $X$ (the "threshold") is a beta variable, and you are asking for the distribution of whether $U \gt X$ ("passes a threshold or not"). Since that's just a binary result, though, I can't figure out how you get to a normalized Beta CDF.