# Joint distribution using jacobian

Tags: self-study, joint-distribution

X and y are independent continuous random variables and have the same distribution Fx = 1- (1/t) for t > 1.  We define two new variables W and Z, where W = min  ( x and Y) and Z = max ( X and Y)
Find the mean of w and mean of z.  I wanted to understand how can we solve this using jacobian transformation.  Here both the variables are in terms of t, so how do we do the transformation and apply the limits.

Comment: You will need considerable care with the Jacobian, because neither transformation is everywhere differentiable and the mapping $(X,Y)\to(W,Z)$ is not one-to-one.  Perhaps the easiest way to obtain the means is to use the ["Tail probability integral"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222497/919).  This obviates any need to compute densities.

Comment: While it doesn't help with the non-smoothness (you'd have to look at whether some generalization of the derivative or something related to [bounded variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation) could help you), the non-one-to-one might be assisted with the [corea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a transformation approach using a Jacobian is the best way to do
this.

By independence, for the minimum we have

$$P(W > t) = P(X > t, Y > t) = P(X > t)P(Y>t) = 1/t^2,$$ for $t > 1.$
So $F_W(t) = P(W \le t) = 1 - 1/t^2.$

Also,
$$F_Z(t) =P(Z \le t) = P(X \le t, Y \le t) = P(X\le t)P(Y\le t) = (1-1/t)^2,$$
for $ t > 1.$

I will leave it to you to find the density function and the expectation of $W$---and to discuss the expectation of $Z.$ Perhaps see [Wikipedia on Pareto distrributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution).