# Which $\mu$ hold so that integral of CDF (from $\mu$ to $\infty$) equals to integral of 1-CDF (from $-\infty$ to $\mu$)?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, integral

What is the $\mu$ s.t. $$\int_{\mu}^{\infty}1-F(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\mu}F(x)dx?$$

Here $F(x) = P(X\leq x).$

Should $\mu$ be the median of X, i.e. $0.5=F(\mu)$? I think $\mu$ should be the point so that $F(\mu) = 1-F(\mu)$, which is the median of X. But how do I derive it mathematically?

Comment: Why do you integrate CDF?

Comment: That $\mu$ to $\infty$ integral is going to be interesting if you don’t mean the PDF (which you do).

Comment: Hint: what's the definition of a median for an absolutely continuous CDF $F$? Can you write the definition of the median in terms of $F$?

Comment: I was using $E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}F(x)dx$, where X is non-negative random variable, to get $E|X-\mu]$. The last step I got was $\int_{\mu}^{\infty}1-F(x)dx + \int_{-\infty}^{\mu}F(x)dx$. But there should be a $\mu$ so that the last two parts of the RHS equals. I wonder what is the $\mu$?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I mean $E(X) = \int_{0}^{\infty} 1-F(x)dx$

Comment: Integrating both sides by parts sheds some light on the question.

Comment: Can you please illustrate a bit more? @whuber F(x) may not be differentiable on R.

Comment: That's a good point, but the resulting integral nevertheless is well-defined as a Riemann-Stieltjes (or Lebesgue-Stieltjes) integral.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222497/919.

Comment: Doesn't this require integrability from $X$ to hold?

Comment: What is "integrability from X"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mean of a variable $X$ can be computed as

$$\mu_X = \int_{0}^{\infty}1-F(x)dx -  \int_{-\infty}^{0} F(x)dx  $$

The mean of a shifted variable $X-\mu_X$ (which equals zero) is computed as

$$0 =  \int_{0}^{\infty}1-F(x+\mu_X)dx - \int_{-\infty}^{0} F(x+\mu_X)dx $$

Or

$$ 0 =   \int_{\mu_X}^{\infty}1-F(x)dx -\int_{-\infty}^{\mu_X} F(x)dx$$

Which is equivalent to your equation.

Therefore the mean $\mu_X$ in these computations is the same as the parameter $\mu$ in your question.