# Prove that $\mathbb{E}\vert X \vert^{a}<\infty$ iff $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{a-1}\mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert \geqslant n)<\infty$

Tags: probability, self-study

Suppose $X$ is a random variable, $a>0$ is a constant. Prove that $\mathbb{E}\vert X \vert^{a}<\infty$ iff $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{a-1}\mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert \geqslant n)<\infty$.

This is a exercise from Mathematical Statistics. Jun Shao. Second edition. EX1.54

For convenience, we suppose that $X$ is non-negative.

I know how to prove in the case $a=1$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}X <\infty$ iff $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X  \geqslant n)<\infty$.

Using the inequality below:
$$
     \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\{X\geqslant n\} \leqslant \mathbb{E}X \leqslant 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\{X\geqslant n\}
$$

This is because:
\begin{align}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\{X\geqslant n\}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k\geqslant n}\mathbb{P}\{k\leqslant X < k+1\}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\mathbb{P}\{k\leqslant X <k+1\} \\
    &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[k I\{k\leqslant X <k+1\}]\leqslant \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[XI\{k\leqslant X <k+1\}] \\
     &=\mathbb{E}X \\
     & \leqslant  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[(k+1)I\{k\leqslant X <k+1\}] \\
     &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)\mathbb{P}\{k\leqslant X <k+1\} \\
     &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\{X\geqslant n\}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\{k\leqslant X <k+1\}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\{X\geqslant n\}+1
\end{align}

So, $\mathbb{E}X <\infty$ iff $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X  \geqslant n)<\infty$.

But for $a>0,a\neq 1$, I have no idea how to change the inequality above to help me to prove the proposition.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I have made some changes. I will appreciate a lot if you can give me some hint.

Comment: I think I know how to use the inequality , I will write down below.

Comment: When you use the expectation formula at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222497/919 you will see this is a special case of a much more general proposition whose validity is obvious geometrically (draw the graphs): *Let $g:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be any bounded measurable non-increasing function.  Then* $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n)\le \int_0^\infty g(x)\,\mathrm dx\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n).$$

Comment: Thanks for my friend's hint. Using the lemma below will be helpful:$$ \mathbb{E}(X^a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}ax^{a-1}\ \mathbb{P}(X\geqslant x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 3):

You can use the more general result that encompasses this specific problem:

***Result $1.$** Let $(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $f$ be a nonnegative real-valued $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}$-measurable function on $\Omega.$ Let $\varphi$ be a nonnegative real-valued increasing, absolutely continuous with continuous derivative almost everywhere. Then $$\int_\Omega \varphi(f(x))~\mathrm d\mu=\int_{[0,~\infty)}\mu\{x\in \Omega:f(x)\geq t\}~\varphi'(t)~\mathrm d\lambda.\tag 1\label 1$$ Also, define for all $n\in\mathbb N, $ \begin{align}
L_n &= \inf_{t \in [n, ~n+1]}\varphi'(t),\\
H_n &= \sup_{t \in [n,~ n+1]}\varphi'(t).\end{align} If $$\frac{L_n}{H_n}\to 1,\tag{a}\label a$$ then $$\int_\Omega \varphi(f(x))~\mathrm d\mu<\infty\iff \sum_{n=1}^\infty \varphi'(n)\mu\{x\in \Omega:f(x)\geq n\}<\infty.\tag 2\label 2$$*

---

**Remarks:**

$\bullet$ For proving $\eqref 1,$ check $\rm [I]$ and for that of $\eqref 2,$ check this Math.SE [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4343991/1074816) - basically the derivation of the latter uses $\eqref 1$ and the assumption $\eqref a. $

$\bullet$ For context, Allen Gut in his book *Probability: A Graduate Course* stated a similar result (and as he is infamous for his hand-wavy writing style, he gave no proof) in Theorem $12.3$ without any assumption of the form $\eqref a. $ That result is, however, false, for it doesn't rule out instances of $\varphi$ with erratic behavior owing to rapid change in $\varphi'$ over small intervals possibly invalidating $\eqref 2 $ (for example, see these [counter-examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317459/expectation-of-nonnegative-random-variable-when-passed-through-nonnegative-incre)). $\eqref a$ tames the behavior of the derivative and as such circumvents possible counter-examples.

$\bullet$ My initial answer was wrong (courtesy to [Taylor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/8336/taylor)) for $n^b\Pr[|X|\geq n]\to 0\nRightarrow \mathbb E[|X|]^b<\infty.$ Take, for example, $$\Pr[X=n]=\frac{k}{n^2\ln n}, ~n\in\{2, 3,\ldots\}$$ (cf. $\rm [II]$).

---

### References:

$\rm [I]$ Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration, *J. Yeh,* World Scientific Publishing, $2014, $ Theorem $23.68, $ pp. $609-610.$

$\rm [II]$ An Introduction to Probability and Statistics, *Vijay K. Rohatgi, A. K. Md. Ehsanes Saleh,* John Wiley & Sons, $2001, $ Remark $3.2.9, $ pp. $74-75.$

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, we suppose that $X$ is non-negative.

We only need to prove that:
\begin{equation}
     \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{a-1}\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant n) \leqslant \mathbb{E}(X^a) \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{a-1}\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant n)+c 
\end{equation}
where $c$ is a constant.

Here is the reason:
\begin{align}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{a-1}\mathbb{P}\{X\geqslant n\}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{a-1}\sum_{k\geqslant n}\mathbb{P}\{k\leqslant X < k+1\} \\
    & \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k\geqslant n}k^{a-1}\mathbb{P}\{k\leqslant X < k+1\} \qquad (\text{We need the condition that $a>1$}) \\
    &=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^a\mathbb{P}\{k\leqslant X <k+1\}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[k^a I\{k\leqslant X <k+1\}] \\
     &\leqslant \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[X^aI\{k\leqslant X <k+1\}] \\
     &=\mathbb{E}(X^a)
\end{align}

The other side of the inequality I haven't proved it.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying [Inforz's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/395269/inforz) work a little:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{a-1}\mathbb{P}\{|X|\geqslant n\}
&=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{a-1}\sum_{k\geqslant n}\mathbb{P}\{k\leqslant |X| < k+1\} \\
&= 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k\geqslant n}\mathbb{E}\left[ n^{a-1}I\{k\leqslant |X| < k+1\}\right] \\
&\leqslant 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k\geqslant n}\mathbb{E}\left[ |X|^{a} I\{k\leqslant |X| < k+1\}\right] \tag{$n \le k \le |X|$}\\
&= 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[ |X|^{a} I\{n \leqslant |X| \}\right] \\
&= 
\mathbb{E}\left[ |X|^{a} \right]
\end{align}