How to understand intuitively the CDF formula for the maximum statistic of three iid rv’s?
Given that all three iid rv’s ($X_1, X_2, X_3$) have CDF $F(x)$, the formula for the CDF $G(y)$ of the largest rv ($Y=X_i$) among the three is:
$G(y)=P(X_1 \leq y) \cdot P(X_2 \leq y) \cdot P(X_3 \leq y)=[F(y)]^3$
I wonder why it is not:
$G(y)=P(X_1 \leq y) \cdot P(X_2 \leq y)$,
Because if $y$ is larger or equal to both $x_1$ and $x_2$, then $y$ will naturally be the maximum, while with the first equation it seems possible that none of the three rv’s ($X_1, X_2, X_3$) will have to be the largest ($y$) of the three (it seems the CDF considers the possibility that all three are less than $y$).
Can anyone share with me how you understand the CDF for the maximum statistic of three iid rv’s intuitively?
This question came up for me while I was solving problem #64 from a sample bank of actuarial probability problems: https://www.soa.org/globalassets/assets/Files/Edu/edu-exam-p-sample-quest.pdf

The solution is also given here: https://www.soa.org/499179/globalassets/assets/files/edu/edu-exam-p-sample-sol.pdf

Please let me know if you have any questions, and thank you in advance!

Check the units: a CDF is defined to be a probability but your proposed formula is a probability times a probability density.  Are you perhaps mixing up the ideas of PDF and CDF?

Perhaps. I was thinking that for the maximum Y of, say, three iid rv’s (X1,X2,X3), it would make sense for its probability to be P(X1<y)P(X2<y), which is that Y is greater than two of the three rv’s, making Y the max; or P(X1<=y)P(X2<=y), the probability that Y is greater than both, times the probability that Y is indeed the value y, or P(Y=y). But like you said, the units may be inconsistent. Can you tell me how you understand the formula for the cdf of the max (for iid rv’s)? With this formula it seems that none of the individual rv’s has to be the max (in P(X1<=y), X1 can be less than Y).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is asked and answered in many posts here on CV -- but they are hard to search for, so allow me to sketch the method.  It comes down to the (readily demonstrable) fact that the event $\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)\le y$ is identical to the event $X_1\le y,\ X_2\le y,\ X_3\le y.$ Because the $X_i$ are independent, compute the probabilities of each separately and multiply, QED.

@whuber Thank you. My problem is that in this case $y$ is larger or equal to the maximum of the three, but doesn’t have to be equal to the maximum of the three, right? What am I missing?

I do not understand your question, because you seem to be assuming something other than what is stated.  The answer comes down to two equivalent characterizations of what it means for the maximum of three numbers not to exceed $y.$  That comes from the very definition of the CDF.

For the problem whose solution I am trying to understand, it asks for the expected value of the largest of the three numbers. I think $y$ represents a cap but not necessarily the largest of the three.

It is really, really important to ask the question you would like answered!  In particular, your question (a) explicitly gives the distribution and (even more importantly) shows that its support has a lower bound (of $1$), which allows you to apply the formula for expectation in terms of the survival function: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222478.  That will make short work of this question.

I understand the solution to the question from the website in my CV question details. I don’t need a solution to be provided for it. The bulk of my question is that while $max(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ won’t exceed $y$, $y$ is not necessarily the maximum of the three—$y$ may be greater. Thank you for the multiple support, I understand the intuition now.
