Do tail bounds on probability translate into bounds on expectations?
Suppose I have a bound of the form:
$$P(X \geq t) \leq \exp(-t^2).$$
Can I say anything about the expectation of $X$, $E[X]$? In particular, can I get a bound on $E[X]$?
Here's the specific case that I'm interested in, a nonparametric regression concentration inequality found in these notes:  https://www.mit.edu/~rakhlin/courses/mathstat/rakhlin_mathstat_sp22.pdf#page=67.09
Given a fixed dataset $x_i$ and function $f$, define the empirical norm to be
$$\|f\|_n^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i f(x_i)^2.$$
Theorem 6 on page 71 proves a bound on the ERM estimator $\hat{f}$ of $f$ in terms of a critical radius $\delta_n$ and an abitrary constant $s$:
$$P(\|\hat{f} - f\|_n^2 \geq 16s\delta_n^2) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{ns\delta_n^2}{2}\right),$$
and claim that this result implies the bound on the expectation:
$$E \|\hat{f} - f\|_n^2 \leq C\left(\delta_n^2 + \frac{1}{n}\right).$$
I'm having trouble figuring out how the bound on the expectation follows from the bound on the tail probability.

Does your bound hold for one particular $t$ (in which case the expectation can still be arbitrarily large), or for all $t$, or for all $t>t_0$ for some $t_0$? I would assume the last, right?

Did you mean to have parentheses around $$-\dfrac{ns\delta_n^2}{2}?$$ so that it's actually $$\exp\left(-\dfrac{ns\delta_n^2}{2}\right)?$$

Because the expectation is no greater than the integral of $\Pr(X\ge t)$ from $t=0$ to $t\to\infty,$ you easily obtain an upper bound.  But what does "in terms of $t$" mean? The expectation is a number--a property of the random variable $X$--so how could it possibly vary??

@whuber: You wrote "Because the expectation is no greater than the integral of $\text{Pr}(X\ge t)$ for $t=0$ to $\to\infty,$...". Not sure I follow: are you saying $$E[X]\le\int_0^\infty \text{Pr}(X\ge t),dt?$$ Why would that be?

NVM, I figured it out: if you change the order of integration, you can show that $$E(X)=\int_0^\infty\int_t^\infty f(u),du,dt = \int_0^\infty\int_0^u f(u),dt,du=\int_0^\infty u,f(u),du,$$as desired.

@AdrianKeister See the last formula in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222497/919.

BTW, there don't exist any random variables with the condition you impose. (Proof: as $t\to-\infty,\Pr(X\ge t)\to 1\gt e^{-t^2}$ for all $t\lt 0.$) You likely intend that $t\ge 0.$

@whuber: Concur. Given that the author's $t=\delta_n^2,$ as well as $X=\left|\hat{f}-f\right|_n^2,$ I assumed everything was non-negative.

Step 1. Taking the cue from whuber, we begin with a non-negative RV $X$ (we say non-negative because eventually $X=\left\|\hat{f}-f\right\|_n^2\ge 0$), and assume that $P(X\ge t)\le e^{-t},$ for all $t\ge 0.$ Now we have:
\begin{align*}
E[X]&=\int_0^\infty u\,f(u)\,du\qquad (f(u)\text{ is the density function for $X$})\\
&=\int_0^\infty f(u)\int_0^udt\,du\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^u f(u)\,dt\,du\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_t^\infty f(u)\,du\,dt\qquad(\text{draw out region for switching order})\\
&=\int_0^\infty P(X\ge t)\,dt\\
&\le \int_0^\infty e^{-t}\,dt\\
&=1.
\end{align*}
So we have shown that if $P(X\ge t)\le e^{-t},$ it must be that $E[X]\le 1.$ We can let $t=s\delta_n^2,$ assuming $s\ge 0,$ and retain the same result.
Step 2. Now we assume that $P(X\ge 16t)\le e^{-nt/2},$ and re-run the logic. We would have:
\begin{align*}
E[X]&=\int_0^\infty u\,f(u)\,du\qquad (f(u)\text{ is the density function for $X$})\\
&=\int_0^\infty f(u)\int_0^udv\,du\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^u f(u)\,dv\,du\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_v^\infty f(u)\,du\,dv\qquad(\text{Let } v=16t)\\
&=16\int_0^\infty\int_{16t}^\infty f(u)\,dt\\
&=16\int_0^\infty P(X\ge 16t)\,dt\\
&\le 16\int_0^\infty e^{-nt/2}\,dt\\
&=\frac{32}{n}\\
&=32\left(\frac1n\right).
\end{align*}
You can certainly add a positive constant inside the parentheses to get the desired result, though it's not clear why you would want a more sloppy inequality than what I've got here. That is, if you assume $s>0$ and still $t>0,$ you can write
$$E[X]\le 32\left(\frac{t}{s}+\frac1n\right)=32\left(\delta_n^2+\frac1n\right).$$
Set $C=32$ and your result is proved.

Thanks for your answer (+1). In the link provided by the question poster, it is stated that the tail bound only applies when $s\geq 1$. This is the source of the $\delta_n^2$ term in the expectation bound, as my answer (hopefully) makes clear.

To compliment Adrian's answer, for your specific problem I think the linked notes imagined the following approach.
As Whuber highlighted in the comments, for any non-negative random variable $X$, we can express the expectation of $X$ as $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\geq x)dx$$ This is true by the Fubini-Tonelli theorem for non-negative random variables since $$\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\geq x)dx=\int_0^{\infty}\int_{\Omega}1_{\{X\geq x\}}d\mathbb{P}dx=\int_{\Omega}\int_0^{\infty}1_{\{X\geq x\}}dxd\mathbb{P}=\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{E}[X]$$
Importantly, $\Vert \hat{f}-f\Vert_n^2$ is such a non-negative random variable. In the link you provided, it is stated in Theorem 6 that $$\mathbb{P}(\Vert \hat{f}-f\Vert_n^2\leq 16s\delta_n^2)\leq \exp \left(-\frac{ns \delta_n^2}{2}\right)$$ holds for any $s\geq 1$. Consider, $$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}[\Vert \hat{f}-f\Vert_n^2]&=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\Vert \hat{f}-f\Vert_n^2\geq x)dx \\
&=\int_0^{16\delta_n^2}\mathbb{P}(\Vert \hat{f}-f\Vert_n^2\geq x)dx+\int_{16\delta_n^2}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\Vert \hat{f}-f\Vert_n^2\geq x)dx \\
&\leq 16\delta_n^2 +\int_{16\delta_n^2}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\Vert \hat{f}-f\Vert_n^2\geq x)dx \\
&=16\delta_n^2+\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\int_{16s\delta_n^2}^{16(s+1)\delta_n^2}\mathbb{P}(\Vert \hat{f}-f\Vert_n^2 \geq x)dx \\
&\leq 16\delta_n^2+\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\int_{16s\delta_n^2}^{16(s+1)\delta_n^2}\mathbb{P}(\Vert \hat{f}-f\Vert_n^2 \geq 16s\delta_n^2)dx \\
&\leq 16\delta_n^2+\sum_{s=1}^{\infty} 16\delta_n^2 \exp\left(-\frac{ns\delta_n^2}{2}\right) \\
&\leq 16\delta_n^2+\int_0^{\infty} 16\delta_n^2 \exp\left(-\frac{ns\delta_n^2}{2}\right)ds \\ 
&= 16\delta_n^2+ \frac{32}{n} \\
&\leq 32\left(\delta_n^2 +\frac{1}{n}\right)\end{align*}$$
And so, $\mathbb{E}[\Vert \hat{f}-f\Vert_n^2]\lesssim \delta_n^2+\frac{1}{n}$.
The additional $\delta_n^2$ term comes from the fact the tail bound only holds for $s\geq 1$. If one splits the integral in Adrian's answer as I have done before applying the tail bound the same answer is obtained.
