Is the expected value monotonically decreasing with respect to the CDF?
When $P(X\ge0)=1$,　$E[X]=\int_0^1(1-F(x))dx\in[0,1]$.
Then, is it true that $E[X]$ is monotonically decreasing with respect to $F(x)$?
If possible, I would like a simple proof of this.
Added:

$F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the random variable $X$, not PDF of X.
“Is $E(X)$ monotonically decreasing with respect to $F(x)$ ” means
$a\ge b\Rightarrow F(a)\ge F(b)\Rightarrow E(F(a)) \le E(F(b))$

Added2:

Thanks for all of the comments and answers! As Sextus Empiricus and whuber have pointed out, my question was written improperly, sorry...
My question should have been like, Is there any $f(X)$ such that satisfies the following? For any random valuable$X$, $E(X)>E(f(X))\Rightarrow \forall x\in \mathbb{R};F_X(x)\le F_{f(x)}(x) $.
And indeed, a function like $f(X)=X-a \:(a\in\mathbb{R}^+)$ is an example.


The condition should be $P(1\ge X\ge 0)=1$ if you want that integral be equal to the expectation of $X$.

"decreasing with respect to F(x)" I am not sure what this means. E[X] is a number for which a conventional binary order relation exist and we can speak about decrease or increase, but F(x) is a function for which such order relation is ambiguous.

Thank you for your kind comment!
Regarding your second question, “ decreasing with respect to F(x) ” means that when $E[X]$ is viewed as a function of $F(x)$, is there a monotonic relationship between $E[X]$ and $F(x)$? If so, is it increasing or decreasing?

You might be interested in Notation conventions for random variables and their distributions

Thank you. That looks very helpful for me.

See also this Wikipedia link about refering to $F(x)$ as a function (which is often used, but not correct notation). The meaning of $F(x)$ is the output of the function $F$ when the input is $x$.

Possibly you are thinking (correctly) of a dominance relationship among functions; namely, $F\ge G$ means that for all real numbers $x,$ $F(x)\le G(x).$ (Notice the reversal of the inequality!) In that sense, $F_X\ge F_Y$ for the CDFs of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ (easily) implies $E[X]\ge E[Y]$ using general formulas proven at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222478.

@whuber Thank you very much. Indeed, it was the dominance relation of the function that I was thinking of.


is there a monotonic relationship between $E[X]$ and $F(x)$?

If you are refering to $F(x)$ as a function, unrelated to a specific value $x$, eg alternatively denoted as $F_X(\cdot)$.
A decreasing monotonic relationship would mean
$$F_X(\cdot) \geq F_Y(\cdot) \implies E[X] \leq E[Y] $$
An increasing monotonic relationship would mean
$$F_X(\cdot) \geq F_Y(\cdot) \implies E[X] \geq E[Y] $$
However, there is no natural/intuitive way to define a concept like inequalities for distribution functions. The meaning of $F_X(\cdot) \geq F_Y(\cdot)$ is ambiguous.
If you are refering to $F(x)$ as a number.
One might consider $F(x)$ as a number when it is about a specific value of $x$.
In this case there is no monotonic relationship. The expectation value depends on an integral for all values $0\leq x \leq 1$ and it does not depend on just one value $x$. For two distributions $F$ and $G$, where for some specific value $x$ we have $F(x) < G(x)$, one has sufficient room to alter the functions at other values such that we can have both $E_F[X] < E_G[X]$ as well as $E_F[X] > E_G[X]$.

Possibly the notation isn't helping here. You write

when $E(X)$ is viewed as a function of $F(x)$

When we speak about the expectation value, then we should consider it as a function of the function $F$ and not as a function of a particular value of that function $F(x)$. So it would be better to write something like

$E(X)$ is viewed as a function of $F$
$E(X)$ is viewed as a function of $F_X$
$E(X)$ is viewed as a function of $F_X(\cdot)$

See also this Wikipedia link about refering to $F(x)$ as a function (which is often used, but not correct notation). The meaning of $F(x)$ is the output of the function $F$ when the input is $x$.

Thank you for your Answer!
I was short on words. The $F(x)$ is not a probability density function but a cumulative distribution function of the random variable $X$. Therefore $F(x)$ is monotonically increasing (non-monotonically decreasing). So I think it is possible to discuss the monotonicity of the function $E(x)$ or $E(F(x))$ with $F(x)$ as an argument. What do you think?

@TomoChang: $E(X)$ is a number, not a function, while $E(x)$ is not defined (as a function of $x$).

@TomoChang I wasn't considering the $F(x)$ as density but as (cumulative) distribution function. The point is that the concept/term 'monotonicity' doesn't make sense. Write out that monotonicity relationship more formally to show what you exactly mean. Like $$a \geq b \implies g(a) \geq g(b)$$ You seem to consider $a$ and $b$ as the cdf's of a variable and $g$ the mapping of a cdf to the mean of the related variable. But for cdf functions there is no clear way to have a relationship like $a \geq b$.

For two different values $x$ and $y$ you can consider relationships like $F(x) \geq F(y)$. However, you can not as easily compare two different CDF functions $F$ and $G$.

Oh you were already thinking of it as a cumulative distribution function. Thank you.
My idea of monotonicity was as follows.
$a\ge b\Rightarrow F(a)\ge F(b)\Rightarrow E(F(a)) \le E(F(b))$

@TomoChang you seem to be considering the function that is the expectation value in a wrong way. You write expressions like $E(F(a))$ and $E(F(b))$, but the expectation is a function of a function $F$, and not a function of a value $F(a)$ or $F(b)$.
